# PHP Zip Archive sporadically creating multiple files

Tags: php, zip, archive

I have a PHP script (running PHP 5.2 on Apache 2.2) that creates a zip archive of files for a user to download.  Everything seems to work just fine; the only issue I have is that periodically multiple files will be created before the ZIP archive is successfully finished.  Example:

archive-name.zip

archive-name.zip.a09600

archive-name.zip.b09600

archive-name.zip.c09600

This does not happen every single time; only periodically - the file is still created but sometimes these extra 'files' are left on the server after it finishes.  The code that creates the ZIP archive is as follows:

```
        $zip_archive = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_archive->open($archiveFullName,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

        if(!file_exists($archiveFullName)) {
            foreach ($completed_file_arr as $zip_file) {
                $isFiller = substr($zip_file,-8) == "_err.txt";
                if(!$isFiller) {
                    $zip_archive->addFile($zip_file,$localname);
                } else $zip_archive->addFromString ($zip_file, "The requested source file could not be found.");
            }
        }

       while(!$zip_archive->close()) sleep(1); //ensure that the ZIP file finishes closing
```

Comment: After this ZIP archive is created; the page is reloaded using javascript.  The page checks to see if a file has been created (and exists) and if it does it serves the download.  What seems to be happening is that the ZIP file is being closed successfully with $zip_archive->close() but the file is not actually wrapping up.  So when the page reloads looking for archive-name.zip the only thing that exists is archive-name.zip.a09600; so it drops down into the ZIP creation segment of the code again until it gets it right.  Not sure what could be causing this to snafu the closing of the ZIP archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to actually be a session related problem; the session data isn't being saved on the first pass because of calls to a function higher up in the code that calls session_write_close() several times (workaround to a known bug with exec() ).  The problem was in preserving/retrieving the data after the session started back up again after that.