# Creating zip archive makes multiple files appended with unpredictable strings

Tags: php, zip, archive

I'm trying to make a PDf downloader where the user can select a couple files and then download a zip of what they selected.  I had it working on my personal server, but on the production server I get an odd error. The zip file is generated, but it's appended with a string of numbers eg;

zipfile.zip.a08752,   zipfile.zip.b08752

Weirder still, if I delete the string off the end and download the file it expands properly.

I read in this topic [PHP Zip Archive sporadically creating multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661914/php-zip-archive-sporadically-creating-multiple-files) that it's an issue with the file attempting to close multiple times, failing and the retrying.

Heres the code for my zip function, though I suspect it's something to do with the configuration of the

```
 function buildZip($params){
    /* Generate unique Id  */

    $downloadid = uniqid();
```

`/* Pull in the order.xml */
if(!empty($_REQUEST['downloadlink'])){  
    if( $params->usexml == true){
        $xml = @simplexml_load_file($params->pdfolder.'/order.xml');
        $order =  $xml->children();
    }else{
        $order = $params->files;        
    }
    /* Create the new Zip */
    $zip = new ZipArchive();   
    if ($zip->open($params->zipname.'version'.$downloadid.'.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die ("Could not open archive");
    }

    /* Generate the download link to output further down the page */
    global $downloadLink;
    $downloadLink = $params->zipname.'version'.$downloadid.'.zip';

    /* Make selected variable available to build the listSelection function */
    global $selected;
    $selected = array();
    $i = 0;


    foreach($order as $el){

        if (isset($_POST[$i]) == true){ 
            //generate list of selected PDF's

            array_push($selected,  $el->name);

            //grab selected pdf's and zip them.
            echo $zip->addFile($params->pdfolder.'/'.$el->link);
            $zip->addFile($params->pdfolder.'/'.$el->link) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: pdf'.$i.'.html");
        }
        $i++;
        }   

        $zip->close();
    }
}
<code>`

For Clarity, I'm pulling in an XML list called order.xml to pull in the array of possible files.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but we're on PHP 5.2.14 and the ZIP class exists, though under phpinfo()  '--enable-zip' is listed under configure command on my server with the working version, but not on the production server. Don't know if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try trimming the weird string of numbers after zipping is done

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem. This is happening because the zip file fails to get created. It's failing because your files are too large. To fix the problem, I had to create multiple smaller zip files. I hope this helps.